# How are static files served through .Handle() targeted?

Tags: go, httpserver, go-chi

*EDIT: I am usinng [`chi`](https://github.com/go-chi/chi) as the router. It works differently from the standard one. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71697898/903011) for the key difference, relevant to my question.*

I am confused about how the files from my static site served by my application are targeted for retrieval.

I have a typical

```
r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("spa")))
```

and the content of `spa` is

```
│   favicon.ico
│   index.html
│
├───css
│       510.e095f672.css
│       app.f05c50d3.css
│       vendor.9add3052.css
│
├───fonts
│       flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNa.1dd1bb36.woff
│       flUhRq6tzZclQEJ-Vdg-IuiaDsNcIhQ8tQ.f54bbe10.woff2
│       KFOkCnqEu92Fr1MmgVxIIzQ.9391e6e2.woff
│       KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmEU9fBBc-.ddd11dab.woff
│       KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmSU5fBBc-.877b9231.woff
│       KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmWUlfBBc-.0344cc3c.woff
│       KFOlCnqEu92Fr1MmYUtfBBc-.b555d228.woff
│       KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxM.9b78ea3b.woff
│
├───icons
│       favicon-128x128.png
│       favicon-16x16.png
│       favicon-32x32.png
│       favicon-96x96.png
│
└───js
        361.136e16c3.js
        510.546967b6.js
        898.3690f332.js
        997.92f440f8.js
        app.42bde279.js
        app.578482b2.js
        vendor.8c20bf3b.js
```

When accessing `http://localhost:15555/` I get in my logs

```
2022-03-31T20:20:10+02:00 | INFO  | / → [::1]:23750
2022-03-31T20:20:10+02:00 | INFO  | /js/vendor.8c20bf3b.js → [::1]:23750
2022-03-31T20:20:10+02:00 | INFO  | /js/app.42bde279.js → [::1]:23751
2022-03-31T20:20:10+02:00 | INFO  | /css/vendor.9add3052.css → [::1]:23752
2022-03-31T20:20:10+02:00 | INFO  | /css/app.f05c50d3.css → [::1]:23753
```

**Only the first call is successful (200), the others are 404**

This first call is finally supposed to retrieve `index.html`, and it does. This is why the linked `.js` and `.css` files are accessed.

This said, trying `http://localhost:15555/` I also get a 404 on the retrieval

```
2022-03-31T20:26:58+02:00 | INFO  | /index.html → [::1]:24233
```

**My questions:**

- why does `/` succeed as it ultimately gets `/index.html`?
- why are other files 404?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? What you describe works just fine for me, see: https://imgur.com/a/gFHHohO

Comment: Also note that when you set up the handler as described, then a request to `/index.html` will not be 404 but instead 301, a redirect, with the location header set to `/`. That's a special case mentioned in http.FileServer's documentation: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http@go1.18#FileServer

Comment: @mkopriva: interesting, I ultimately had to add a wildcard to my handler for it to work (I added an answer, hopefully correct)

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem, the handler must be

```
r.Handle("/*", http.FileServer(http.Dir("spa")))
```

I thought that `/` would match everything and that a wildcard was not needed.

Comment: Note that wildcard is not needed for routing handlers with the stdlib's net/http package. You are probably not using the standard lib to route the handlers and that unnamed 3rd party lib obviously does require you to supply a wildcard.

Comment: Mentioning what tools you use in the question, especially if they are 3rd party, can be quite useful to anyone who would like to help you.

Comment: @mkopriva: ha, that's a good point. I am new to Go and was under the impression that there is a homogeneity around methods that are called the same way, same type etc. That was obviously a wrong preconception. The library I used was [`chi`](https://github.com/go-chi/chi)